# R: Automated ifelse calculation in matrix for every row

Tags: r, if-statement, matrix

for a large matrix [n,1], I want to find out for every row, if a value is smaller 0.1 and if the following value (in the following row) is bigger 0.1.

```
ifelse(matrix[1,1]<0.1 & matrix[2,1]>0.1, "1", "0")

ifelse(matrix[2,1]<0.1 & matrix[3,1]>0.1, "1", "0")

ifelse(matrix[3,1]<0.1 & matrix[4,1]>0.1, "1", "0")`
```

How can I automate this calculation for every row?

Comment: Yes, I tried it before, but it is my first loop and I do not know how to write it in this case. for (i in matrix) {
+ ifelse(matrix[i,1]<0.1 & matrix[i+1,1]>0.1, "1", "0")}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easily vectorized:

```
set.seed(6L);
N <- 10L; m <- matrix(rnorm(N,0.1,0.01),ncol=1L);
m;
##             [,1]
##  [1,] 0.10269606
##  [2,] 0.09370015
##  [3,] 0.10868660
##  [4,] 0.11727196
##  [5,] 0.10024188
##  [6,] 0.10368025
##  [7,] 0.08690796
##  [8,] 0.10738622
##  [9,] 0.10044873
## [10,] 0.08951603
m[-length(m)]<0.1 & m[-1L]>0.1;
## [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

If you want the actual row indexes:

```
which(m[-length(m)]<0.1 & m[-1L]>0.1);
## [1] 2 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that you want to want to do n-1 comparisons, and use the `head()` function to extract all except the last element of matrix[,1], and do equivalently with `tail()` to get all except the first element.

`ifelse(head(matrix[,1],-1)<0.1 & tail(matrix[,1],-1)>0.1, "1", "0")`